# Can't update ROS because of ros-latest.list file

Tags: ubuntu, package, command-line-interface, ros, apt

I have been trying to install a ROS melodic. I need it for running some launch files. Currently when I check the ros version (on my raspberry pi 4 running Ubuntu 20.04) by running the command:

```
rosversion -d
```

It outputs: `Debian`

When I follow installation guides like these:
http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu ,
https://choreonoid.org/en/manuals/latest/ros/install-ros.html

I continue to get this error at the `sudo apt update` command
[image]

From what I understand (granted, I am still a beginner), is that the repository linked on the ros-latest.list file does not direct to the appropriate repo.

This said, I have tried multiple ways to change that text. I though that with the command:
`sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'`
That is what changes it, but when I search of the /etc/apt/source.list.d directory, the text in the ros-latest.launch file has not change. I also tried manually changing it in the terminal with the command
`sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list`

and it still doesn't work :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot install Melodic on 20.04 as someone else already said. Instead, what you should be doing is using [Noetic](http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu), the release for 20.04. It can be installed via `sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full`

Comment: I have followed this tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu for installing noetic. The same problem still remains. Once I get to the sudo apt update, the same exact error appears.

Comment: @AngelOrtiz first, you would need to remove the old listing from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list`. The being said, if you're getting that *exact* same error message it's because you don't have 20.04 installed. You have 21.04 which doesn't have a compatible ROS distro at present.

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 21.04. My bad. I am trying to remove the ros-latest.list file through the GUI and can't. Is this done through the terminal? I am still no able to run sudo apt update without receiving the error on the question.

Comment: @AngelOrtiz If you're running 21.04 nothing above matters or will fix the problem. You cannot run ros on 21.04.

Comment: I see. But I am still unable to run succesfully sudo apt update because of the issue of thar ros-latest.list file in the etc/apt/sources.list.d folder. How can I remove it so my update can run smoothly?

Answer (score 1):

1. ROS melodic packages are only available on Ubuntu Artful (17.10), Bionic (18.04 LTS) and Debian Stretch.
2. As I know, there is no easy way to install ROS melodic on Ubuntu 20.04, but you need to manually compile all packages from source code and there're many dependency issues to solve.
3. However, if you still want to run ROS melodic on Ubuntu 20.04 for whatever reason, I suggest you run it in docker.